# Use case statement for parameter for column name in sql where clause

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I have been looking all day for a solution that works for my situation. I have found some things that are very similar but don't work for my situation, I tried them.

Here is the scenario; I have two table base and partdetails. I have an asp website (internal ONLY) that has drop down lists to select the parameters for a SQL query that fills a data grid view.

My problem is this, I need to be able, based on the drop down list boxes on the page, assign the column name that the criteria that is entered to be searched for.

Here is the query that I am trying to define: (This one returns 0 rows)

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = ("Select ba.referenceid, ba.partnum, pd.width, pd.length, CONVERT(varchar(12), pd.dateentered, 101) As [dateentered], ba.partqty, ba.status, ba.material From tbl_dlbase ba Join tbl_partdetails pd On ba.referenceid = pd.referenceid Where Case @field1 When 'part #' Then 'ba.partnum' When 'Spacing' Then 'pd.spacing' When 'Surface' Then 'pd.surface' When 'Height' Then 'pd.height' When 'Thickness' Then 'pd.thickness' End Like '%' + @criteria1 + '%'")

sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", ddlSc1.SelectedItem.Text)
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@criteria1", txbCriteria1.Text)
```

This is the latest version of the SQL statement that I have tried. I need to be able to set the field/column name based on the selection from the drop down list ddlsc1 on the asp page.

I have also been trying the queries in Studio manager to see if maybe I have fat fingered something but it also returns 0 rows so I know something is wrong with the query.

So how can I set the column name field using a parameter for the name. I know this is a huge security concern with SQL injection but this is an internal only site, and more importantly my boss said he wants it done with variables.

Comment: I thought it was dynamic considering I am using variables for names. What exactly is dynamic SQL then?

Comment: You don't need dynamic here, from the looks of your current query I don't think you know what you need.

Comment: "*I have been looking all day for a solution that works for my situation. I have found some things that are very similar but don't work for my situation, I tried them.*"  Umm, if this were true, it seems like you'd already know what Dynamic SQL is (this is a *very* common request on the internet). Please show us what you've already tried that "don't work for my situation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see a problem with this other than you have single quotes around your `THEN` values.  Does this fix it?

```
SELECT ba.referenceid
    ,ba.partnum
    ,pd.width
    ,pd.length
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), pd.dateentered, 101) AS [dateentered]
    ,ba.partqty
    ,ba.STATUS
    ,ba.material
FROM tbl_dlbase ba
JOIN tbl_partdetails pd ON ba.referenceid = pd.referenceid
WHERE CASE @field1
        WHEN 'part #'
            THEN ba.partnum
        WHEN 'Spacing'
            THEN pd.spacing
        WHEN 'Surface'
            THEN pd.surface
        WHEN 'Height'
            THEN pd.height
        WHEN 'Thickness'
            THEN pd.thickness
        END LIKE '%' + @criteria1 + '%'
```